# pg_search for autocomplete or substring search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

Hi i am using pg_search gem and i have multiple columns to search from but i want to be able to do a substring search of these columns as well but seems like so far pg_search is only doing a full_text search

```
class Application
  pg_search_scope :search, against: %i[email full_name id_no company_reg_no id vehicle_reg_no], using: {
    tsearch: {
      any_word: true
    },
    trigram: {
      only: %i[vehicle_reg_no full_name]
    }
  }
end
```

This is my current code for my pg_search_scope.

I have the following records

```
id full_name vehicle_reg_no
1    Nich      WQD8812
2    Nicholas  WQD8821
3    Nic Wong  WQD 8831
```

But when i do `Application.search('Nic')` i only get one record which is record no 3. When i am expecting to get all 3 records since they should match with the search query.

Not sure how to set this up using pg_search.

Comment: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#prefix-postgresql-84-and-newer-only

Comment: Take a look this one: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/optimizing-full-text-search-with-postgres-tsvector-columns-and-triggers

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe as you can see in my code, i am already using trigram operator but still facing the same issue.